# Calling subject.onNext() inside doOnSubscribe

Tags: java, rx-java2

Why calling `subject.onNext(o)` inside `doOnSubscribe` does not any effect, however calling `subject.onComplete()` causes the stream to terminate!?

```
final PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();

    final Observable<Integer> observable = subject.doOnSubscribe(new Consumer<Disposable>() {
        @Override
        public void accept(@NonNull Disposable disposable) throws Exception {
            System.out.println("disposable = [" + disposable + "]");
            subject.onNext(1);
            //or
            Observable.just(2, 3).subscribe(subject);
        }
    });

    observable.subscribe(new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
            System.out.println("d = [" + d.isDisposed() + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onNext(Integer integer) {
            System.out.println("item = [" + integer + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("e = [" + e + "]");
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            System.out.println("onComplete");
        }
    });/*
    expected:
    disposable = [false]
    d = [false]
    item = 1
    item = 2
    item = 3
    onComplete
    but received :
    disposable = [false]
    d = [false]
    onComplete
    */
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When subscribing to a `Subject` in 2.x, the `Disposable` representing the connection is traversing the `onSubscribe()` chain before the particular `Observer` becomes visible for an `onNext`. You can see this if you call `hasObservers` from `onSubscribe` where it will return false up until the `onSubscribe` actually returns.

This is required by the Observable protocol as it is not allowed to run `onSubscribe` and `onNext` concurrently and `onSubscribe` must happen before `onNext`. If this rule wasn't held, a concurrent call to `Subject.onNext` would run before or even at the same time than a `Observer.onSubscribe` call and find a likely unprepared consumer.

Since `PublishSubject` doesn't retain any `onNext` calls, unobserved `onNext` items are dropped. Depending on the use case, you should instead use `BehaviorSubject` or `yourSubject.startWith(initialValue).subscribe()` to get a value before any other `onNext` from the `Subject`.